How to quickly enter a year of tabs? (Google Spreadsheet)
I designed a reservations overview for our hotel's restaurant. Not worked with Spreadsheets before and still turned out pretty well I think.
But now there must be a (copy) tab for each day of the year to put in the reservations.
How do I do this in the most efficient way?
If anyone knows how to simplify it even more, for example by dividing it into months instead of all days (365 tabs!) then I would be very happy.
Thanks for thinking with me, unfortunately I have not found the solution on the internet so far.
I have always duplicated the designed tab 365 times so far. Works but very labor intensive.
